# Where to find list of WiX localization tokens?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I was updating `.wxs` file and stumbled upon `loc.NewerVersionInstalled` token in some other example `.wxs` file.

I can't find any kind of list of any other `loc.*` tokens. I tried to search `NewerVersionInstalled` in WiX `bin` and `SDK` directories files and [WiX website](http://wixtoolset.org/) without any luck.

Example:

```
<MajorUpgrade 
  DowngradeErrorMessage="loc.NewerVersionInstalled" 
  Schedule="afterInstallInitialize" 
  IgnoreRemoveFailure="no" 
  AllowSameVersionUpgrades="no" 
  AllowDowngrades="no" 
/>
```

And now if I try to install the `.msi` file I get:

> Another version of this product is already installed.  Installation of
>   this version cannot continue.  To configure or remove the existing
>   version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel.

Are these part of WiX, Windows Installer (msiexec) or some sort of Windows internal tokens?

---

Few examples that could use these `loc.*` tokens if they exist:

```
<Condition 
  Message="You must have Administrative rights on this machine to install [ProductName].">
  <![CDATA[Privileged]]>
</Condition>
```

To something like:

```
<Condition 
  Message="loc.NeedsAdminPrivileges">
  <![CDATA[Privileged]]>
</Condition>
```

Second example:

```
<Property Id="DiskPrompt" Value="$(var.ProductShortName) Installation [1]" />
```

To:

```
<Property Id="DiskPrompt" Value="loc.InstallerIntro" />
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you creating a custom localized message?

Comment: @Oscar Just the opposite. Trying to use these internal tokens as much as possible everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are many localization files in Wix source code. As per install UI in english, the relevant file is WixUI_en-us.wxl

Localization files have *.wxl extension, in case you need to find localized strings for other components.

https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_en-us.wxl

Comment: I went through these files and couldn't find NewerVersionInstalled.

Comment: @raspi Sorry, but can't find that concrete message in Wix sources :-(

Comment: Only this, but it isn't a localization file, and seems to be a test:
https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/test/src/WixTestTools/MSIExecArguments.cs line 290